# MATLAB how to Use ODE solvers?

Tags: matlab, ode

I have an ODE and I want to eliminate `x`. 
Can some one help me with this in MATLAB?

Equation

```
   dy/dx=(-((y^2)/(j*omega*eox)) + ((j*omega*(q^2)*nbt)/(1+(j*omega*tau0*e^(2*k*x)))) )
```

Values of constants:

```
eox = 8.85*10.^-12;
omega = 1;
j=-1.^(1/2);
q=1.6*(10.^(-19));
nbt=(10.^(-10));
tau0=10.^(-4);
k=1;
e=2.71828182846;
y = 0 to 80
```

Comment: If you just want one-shot solutions, there is always the wolfram alpha website

Comment: I tried to solve with symbolic but I want here x to be eliminated.

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "eliminate". Also, please write the *full* equation; what you've written is just a jungle of parameters and mathematical operators :)

Comment: I want to have dy/dx in terms of y and omega and I want to eliminate x from this equation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *I want to have dy/dx in terms of y and omega and I want to eliminate x from this equation*

In your above code omega is a constant, so I'm assuming that it is only a parameter.

What you've currently shown us is simply an ODE in the form,

```
dy/dx = f(x,y)
```

You cannot eliminate "x" from this DE, and there's no need to do so as the equation is already in precisely the right form for use with any of the ode solvers, like ode45 for example.

If you want to run a solver on this with lots of different values of parameter omega, that can be done pretty easily using "anonymous functions". But you'll probably have to refine your question a bit before anyone can help you more.